# Errors appear on android old version

Tags: android

Good day. I would like to ask for a help. I want to modify my android billing system. When I open
the application. There's an error appear on the compiler. I am using the old version of android
studio. Version 2.2.3.

Error:
C:\Users\TziH\Desktop\Desktop File\BlueToothDEMO33\app\src\main\res\layout\main.xml
Error:(140, 30) String types not allowed (at 'orientation' with value 'horizontal;').

This is the error appear on my screen

[image: 1]

I tried updating android studio but still the problem occur.

Comment: What is the project SDK version?

Comment: sdk platform-tools is 34

Comment: There's a typo error in the value. The correct name is "sensorPortrait"

Comment: What version of Android Studio have you updated to? Can you update your question again with the updated configuration? It is recommended to [upgrade your Android Studio to 4.2 or higher for the best development experience](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/setup-sdk#get-studio).

Comment: And may I know if I have missed anything? I cannot see any wording like ```screenOrientation``` being used in your code...

Comment: Also can you try if there is any problem using SDK 31 with your updated Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"sensorPortrait" was the correct code for the updated version. TY